# Filling Object with JSON result in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am returning multiple records as JSON and need to fill an object with them. How is done in Dart?

```
HomeCategory(0, Icons.check, Colors.blue[800], "Check In", [Task(0, "Check In", true),]),
```

The JSON result has all this data.

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize the JSON string into a map:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

...

Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj = json.decode(jsonString);
```

Then create a factory constructor for your class that converts the map into your object:

```dart
class HomeCategory {
  final int id;
  final String iconCode;
  final String colorCode;
  final String message;
  final List<Task> tasks;

  HomeCategory(
    this.id,
    this.iconCode,
    this.colorCode,
    this.message,
    this.tasks,
  );

  HomeCategory.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> jsonObj) {
    int id = jsonObj['id'];
    String iconCode = jsonObj['iconCode'];
    String colorCode = jsonObj['colorCode'];
    String message = jsonObj['message'];

    List<Task> tasks = [];
    var tasksObj = jsonObj['tasks'];
    if (tasksObj != null && tasksObj is List) {
      tasks = tasksObj.map((taskObj) => Task.fromJson(taskObj)).toList();
    }

    return HomeCategory(id, iconCode, colorCode, message, tasks);
  }
```

Tailor the above code to the structure of your `HomeCategory` and `Task` classes as well as the structure of your JSON. (You're going to need to give the `Task` class a `fromJson` constructor as well, of course.)

---

EDIT: If your incoming JSON object is a list, you can simply change how you use the deserialized json object:

```dart
List<dynamic> jsonList = json.decode(jsonString);
List<HomeCategory> homeCategories = jsonList.map((jsonObj) => HomeCategory.fromJson(jsonObj)).toList();
```

Comment: thanks. HomeCategory is a list as well, it will be multiple records.

Comment: @SamCromer Don't treat `HomeCategory` as "a list as well". Treat the JSON object as "a list of HomeCategory objects".